# Swing - Stacking Timers into each other (Is this bad practice?)

Tags: java, swing, timer

So, basically, I've got a swing game that has a swing timer. This is to wait after the computer has calculated what it will do until it turns because human's can't look so fast. When that timer executes, the next turn begins and the computer AI takes its turn.
Thing is, when both players are computers, this will theoretically stack timers into each other ad infinitum because inside the timer, the same timer will (indirectly) be called again, and again, and again. Does this generate data leaks and if so, what else can I do to archieve the same "waiting" process?

So, in pseudocode, this is what is happening:

```
public void computerTurn() {
    ...
    new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        ....
        if (foo)
            computerTurn()
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not generate an infinite stack of timers or leaks, so it won't be a problem (since `computerTurn` doesn't call the code inside the `ActionListener` directly). Using the built-in repeat functionality is still preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
ActionListener listener = (e) -> {
  if (!foo) { // if not foo, don't repeat anymore
    ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
  }
}

Timer timer = new Timer(1000, listener);
timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.start();
```